# Login still redirect to the same page even when using different email to log in

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I'm using Firestore and Nuxt for my project.

I want my application to redirect the pages based on their user type when they are logged in.

I want if userType = contractor, when login it will redirect to /WPC/DashboardWPC.
I want if userType = subcontractor, when login it will redirect to /Form/SectionA.

But currently, when logging in, it will always redirect to /Form/SectionA. I don't want that. I want it to log to different pages based on their user type.

Any advice?

```
    Login() {
      let credentials = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
      };
      this.$store
        .dispatch("user/Login", credentials)
        .then(() => {

          const users = firestore.collection('Users')

          users.get().then(() => {
            if (firestore.collection('Users').where("userType", "==", "subcontractor")) {
              window.location = "/Form/SectionA";
            } else if (firestore.collection('Users').where("userType", "==", "contractor")) {
              //console.log(snapshot.docs[0].data())
              window.location = "/WPC/DashboardWPC";
            } else {
              window.location = "/BWG/DashboardBWG";
            }
          })
      }).catch((err) => {
        alert(err.message)
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how are you allowing your users to log in, but the [signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password) is the method Firebase provides.

I have no experience with `nuxt.js` but something like this should give you a general idea:

```
Login() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
       .then((user) => {
            const _userDoc = firestore.collection('Users').doc(user.uid).get();
            const userType = _userDoc.data['userType'];
            if(userType == "subcontractor"){
                window.location = "/Form/SectionA";
            }
            else if(userType == "contractor"){
                window.location = "/WPC/DashboardWPC";
            }
            else{
                window.location = "/BWG/DashboardBWG";
            }
           
        },
        (err) => {
            alert(err.message);
        },
    );
}
```

Also, for registering your users you can use the [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) method.

Comment: Apologise for late reply. Now I cannot log in. It popups alert box "_userDoc.data is not a function"

Comment: Edited my code, but as I said, I don't have experience with nuxt.js and I have no way to reproduce it. Don't use my code as a copy paste but rather as a reference.